# when I click on link on my website it is not opening? why is it so?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a strange problem that when I click on `special-treatment.html` link, the link is not working? can someboby help me please.

**My html code is here**

```
<div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-right">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">


        <li class="dropdown"><a href="special-treatment.html" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Special Treatments </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="psoriasis-treatment.html">Psoriasis Treatment</a></li>
                <li><a href="arthritis-treatment.html">Arthritis Treatment</a></li>
                <li><a href="paralysis-treatment.html">Paralysis Treatment</a></li>
                <li><a href="asthma-treatment.html">Asthma Treatment</a></li>
                <li><a href="diabetes-treatment.html">Diabetes Treatment</a></li>
                <li><a href="hypertension-treatment.html">Hypertension Treatment</a></li>
                <li><a href="facial-paralysis-treatment.html">Facial Paralysis Treatment</a></li>
                <li><a href="cervical-spondylosis-treatment.html">Cervical Spondylosis Treatment</a></li>
                <li><a href="schelerosis-treatment.html">Multiple Schelerosis Treatment</a></li>
            </ul><!-- end dropdown-menu -->
        </li><!-- end standard drop down -->

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="knowledge-base.html" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Knowledge Base  </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="panchakarma.html">Panchakarma</a></li>
                <li><a href="women-health.html">Women Health</a></li>
                <li><a href="herbs.html">Medicinal Herbs</a></li>
                <li><a href="yoga.html">Yoga</a></li>
                <li><a href="music-therapy.html">Music Therapy</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="#.html">Appointment Form</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="principles-of-ayurveda.html">Principles of Ayurveda</a></li>
            </ul><!-- end drop down menu -->
        </li><!-- end drop down -->



    </ul><!-- end navbar-nav -->
</div><!-- #navbar-collapse-1 -->
```

Comment: where is your html code?!

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you want that link to go somewhere, why did you add `data-toggle` etc? That is to open / close a dropdown or something.

Comment: what is the location of all html files relative to current html?

Comment: You are going to create a dropdown list, and special-treatment is the item that when you click opens dropdown. So why you need to cancel this behavior?

Comment: just check this link test5.xsisinformatics.com

Comment: @ Sina Sadrzadeh no special-treatment.html is a different page which i have made but its not working when i click on that link.

Comment: do you use any third-party library for creating `dropdown`?

Comment: you see that `knowledge base` link is not working too. because you made it a dropdown

Comment: no there is not other thing than css styling of dropdown menus

Comment: Here's a fiddle for you to see. The dropdown works fine, I believe the question is how to make the top link work as a normal link as well. http://jsfiddle.net/Lctfn3j2/

Comment: @ Sina, it is also not working.what is the main reason for that

Comment: @ Roope, special-treatment.html is not working yet jsfiddle.net/Lctfn3j2

Comment: in `jsfiddle` I can see, when you click on `Special Treatments`, it opened dropdown menu, so you have to choose, if you want after clicking on that href, if to open dropdown menu or follow link to `special-treatment.html`... but why both??!

Comment: just check this site http://keralaayurvediccentre.com/index.aspx.in this both special-treatment and the dropdown works differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see you making this work is like this:

You can't have the Special Treatment button be both a link and a button for the dropdown, so add in a drop down arrow and then have the special treatments as a link.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lctfn3j2/1/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="special-treatment.html">Special Treatments</a><a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/down-arrow-in-small-circle_318-25293.jpg" width="30" /></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="psoriasis-treatment.html">Psoriasis Treatment</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="arthritis-treatment.html">Arthritis Treatment</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="paralysis-treatment.html">Paralysis Treatment</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="asthma-treatment.html">Asthma Treatment</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="diabetes-treatment.html">Diabetes Treatment</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="hypertension-treatment.html">Hypertension Treatment</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="facial-paralysis-treatment.html">Facial Paralysis Treatment</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="cervical-spondylosis-treatment.html">Cervical Spondylosis Treatment</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="schelerosis-treatment.html">Multiple Schelerosis Treatment</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- end dropdown-menu -->
        </li>
        <!-- end standard drop down -->
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="knowledge-base.html">Knowledge Base</a><a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle"><img src="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/down-arrow-in-small-circle_318-25293.jpg" width="30" /></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="panchakarma.html">Panchakarma</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="women-health.html">Women Health</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="herbs.html">Medicinal Herbs</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="yoga.html">Yoga</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="music-therapy.html">Music Therapy</a>
                </li>
                <!--<li><a href="#.html">Appointment Form</a></li>-->
                <li><a href="principles-of-ayurveda.html">Principles of Ayurveda</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- end drop down menu -->
        </li>
        <!-- end drop down -->
    </ul>
    <!-- end navbar-nav -->
</div>
<!-- #navbar-collapse-1 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted it to act as a hover drop down nav use something like this (this example uses bootstrap, but there are simpler ones out there that are pure css):

(These examples will open the page when clicked, but might not do it in CodePen)

http://codepen.io/unavezfui/pen/okzJi

Example of simpler pure CSS version: http://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/xhiJH

```js
/*
No use bootstrap js library
*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav .dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-menu{
   margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http:////netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a id="drop1" role="button" href="http://www.google.com">Dropdown 1</a>
    <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a id="drop2" role="button" href="http://www.google.com">Dropdown 2</a>
    <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a id="drop3" role="button" href="http://www.google.com">Dropdown 3</a>
    <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
  
</ul>
```